# My app crashes when using addView()

Tags: android, viewgroup

Im a noob at android. My app keeps crashing whenever I use ViewGroup addView() method but works when I use the Activity addContentView() method.

The reason I want to use addView() instead of addContentView() is that I want to be able to remove the layouts when not needed which is not possible with addContentView().

Code:
MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //CAMERA VIEW
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //GRAPHICS VIEW
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());
    //crash
    //rootView.addView(glSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //not crash
    addContentView(glSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    glSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

    //CONTROLS VIEW
    View ctrlLayout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_controls, rootView);
        //crash
        //rootView.addView(ctrlLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //not crash
    addContentView(ctrlLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ctrlLayout.bringToFront();
    textView = (TextView)ctrlLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    rtTextView = (TextView)ctrlLayout.findViewById(R.id.rt_text);
    btnStart = (Button)ctrlLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_controls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rt_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/str_rttext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rt_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/str_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

I changed my code as suggested by FD_

ViewGroup rootView  = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
Now when I call setContentView(rootView) at the end of onCreate function, it crashes.

Here is the logcat:

```
02-16 08:00:28.142: I/dalvikvm(2153): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/view/View;.isLayoutDirectionInherited:Z
02-16 08:00:28.142: I/dalvikvm(2153):   method requires 12+20+4=36 bytes, fp is 0xb02fe320 (32 left)
02-16 08:00:28.152: I/dalvikvm(2153):   expanding stack end (0xb02fe300 to 0xb02fe000)
02-16 08:00:28.152: I/dalvikvm(2153): Shrank stack (to 0xb02fe300, curFrame is 0xb0303ec4)
02-16 08:00:28.152: D/AndroidRuntime(2153): Shutting down VM
02-16 08:00:28.152: W/dalvikvm(2153): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aeab90)
02-16 08:00:28.932: D/dalvikvm(2153): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 117K, 6% free 3266K/3448K, paused 80ms, total 86ms
02-16 08:00:29.382: D/dalvikvm(2153): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 356K, 11% free 3423K/3844K, paused 46ms, total 47ms
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153): Process: com.example.previewcamera, PID: 2153
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5713)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5714)
02-16 08:00:29.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2153):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetRes
02-16 08:00:29.632: D/dalvikvm(2153): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 548K, 16% free 3386K/4000K, paused 54ms, total 55ms
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call `setContentView()` before you can use `findViewById()` in your `Activity`. Additionally, `findViewById()` returns views that are included in the content view and identified by the *id* value passed as the argument, so passing a layout resource will never work.

Another option is to inflate the View yourself, using `LayoutInflater`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Comment: That did the job. My app is not crashing anymore but now the addView() is not displaying anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: And I already tried to change the layout params of glSurfaceView and ctrlView to WRAP_CONTENT but still not working.

Comment: If you are using the approach above (LayoutInflater), you'll haver to call setContentView(rootView); at the end of onCreate.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing your approach. I tried to call setContentView(rootView) but whenevr I call it my app crash.

Comment: I cannot give you any hints without seeing your logcat and knowing what exactly happens.

Comment: You seem to be adding a View as a child of itself, but I cannot tell you where, because I don't have the code.

Comment: I added a new framelayout to the activity_main instead of inflating it and added the two views inside the framelayout to solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left in order tk mark this question as answered.

Comment: ..um.. I seem to be revisiting this answer more frequently that I wish I did.

Answer (score 24):

For others that end up here trying to track down that error using custom views, double check that you're inflating correctly. The following change resolved my issues.

Error:

```
View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.foo, this);
addView(view);
```

Works fine:

```
View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.foo, null);
addView(view);
```

Comment: Actually using View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.foo, this, false); is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while using attachToRoot = true

```
final View submitButton = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate
            (R.layout.view_button_simple, rootView, true);
```

I had to change it to

```
final View submitButton = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate
            (R.layout.view_button_simple, rootView, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessign wrong layout we also result to app crash. check whether you have added a layout with same id in your popup layout